# How to deploy Angular 17 ssr mode on firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I have been researching this for a week now and not getting a clear answer.
I have developed an angular 17 project in ssr mode, installed firebase from npm created the build, firebase init hosting and said N for set up as single page app, gave the directory for dist/my-project/server. I am not able to view the page i deployed as it says index.html is not found and then I did rewrites for index.server.html then it says the mime type is given as text/html for a polyfills.js.
Anyone who can tell the way to actually deploy would be really really helpful.

Also for firebase initialization I have given all yes except for the one single page and github initialization. If at all its very hard to give here, it would really really help if anyone provides of any links where it is documented so I can follow the documents

Answer (score 0):

I went through a lot of headache with this too. It ended up being my rewrite rules in my firebase.json. I set my hosting.public to be "dist//browser" and then removed the rewrite rules. After running firebase deploy my fresh Angular 17 app actually loaded. Hopefully this solves your problem as well.

Here is my firebase.json file for reference

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/<my-project-name>/browser",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```